# Show compactness of the given set.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$\Big\{\Big(\dfrac{1}{m},\dfrac{1}{n}\Big):m,n\in\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}\Big\}\cup\{(0,0)\}\cup\Big\{\Big(\dfrac{1}{m},0\Big):m\in\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}\Big\}\cup\Big\{\Big(0,\dfrac{1}{n}\Big):n\in\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}\Big\}$

Let, $S$ be the above set.

I know this set is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but don't know how to show that.

I know that this set is closed and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff, but not compact.

Can anyone tell me how to show $S$ is compact?

---

**Update: I think I found the answer! Note that every sequence of point of $S$ has convergent subsequence. Hence, $S$ is compact, since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is metrizable space. (Munkres, Theorem 28.2)**

Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we know the compact sets in $\Bbb{R}^2$ are compact if and only if they are closed and bounded. You said you know that it is closed, so it remains to prove that it is bounded. That is, it remains to show that you can fit this whole set inside some epsilon-ball. Do you see how you might do this?

Comment: My post is a waste. I just made a big mistake overseeing that $\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}$. Thanks for the solution. (my mistake was thinking $\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}\cup \{1/n : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}$)

Comment: No problem! And it's not a waste! Sometimes you have to make mistakes in order to learn. :)